# Как хэшировать строку на js?

Tags: javascript

Нужно спросить у пользователя его пароль на js и передать его в php

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['psw'])==false){//Нельзя допустить цикла
    ?>
    <script>document.location="ask_password.php?psw="+prompt("password");</script>
    <?php
}
if(isset($_GET['psw'])){
    echo $_GET['psw'];
}
else{
    echo "Error!";
}
```

?>

Но это небезопасно. Как хэшировать пароль на js на md5?

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+md5)

Comment: Так и md5 не безопасно... Почему нельзя использовать [сессию](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)? К чему все эти передачи пароля через GET параметры?

Comment: пароль передаётся через POST, а не GET. А уже на сервере надо его хэшировать

Comment: @XelaNimed Имеет ли js доступ к $_SESSION?

Comment: Зачем здесь JS? Форма посылает POST запрос на сервер с именем пользователя и пароля. На сервере полученный пароль хешируется, из БД выбирается пользователь с полученным хешем. Успешно - открыли сессию записали в неё всё что нужно и ответили клиенту HTTP200, нет такой комбинации пользователя и пароля - ответили HTTP401. Механизм/алгоритм хеширования не должен быть общедоступным, т.к. он, по идее, должен подмешивать "соль", выполнять дополнительное хеширование разными хеш-алгоритмами. И конечно не нужно использовать чувствительную информацию в качестве значений любых GET-параметров.